Anchor test: signer don't get fees deducted when doing a transaction?
I'm trying to see how much fee are used for a transactions within Anchor test.  It seems there no fees being taken from the one signing the transaction?
I was expecting to see the balance decrease, but it remains the same? How can I solve this?
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("1111111111111111111");

#[program]
pub mod addition {
    use super::*;

    pub fn add(_ctx: Context<Add>, a: u64, b: u64) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Result: {}", a + b);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Add<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}

import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";

describe("simple-addition", () => {
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.Addition;

  it("Add numbers and check user balance", async () => {
    // Create a new user keypair
    const user = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    
    // Airdrop 1 SOL to the user
    const signature = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
      user.publicKey,
      1 * anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(signature);

    // Check initial balance
    const initialBalance = await provider.connection.getBalance(user.publicKey);
    console.log(`User initial balance: ${initialBalance } lamports`);

    // Perform addition with user as signer
    await program.methods
      .add(new anchor.BN(5), new anchor.BN(3))
      .accounts({
        user: user.publicKey,
      })
      .signers([user])
      .rpc();

    // Check final balance
    const finalBalance = await provider.connection.getBalance(user.publicKey);
    console.log(`User final balance: ${finalBalance } lamports`);
    console.log(`Transaction cost: ${(initialBalance - finalBalance) } lamports`);
  });
});

My output is:
  simple-addition
User initial balance: 1000000000 lamports
User final balance: 1000000000 lamports
Transaction cost: 0 lamports


The user is not the fee payer of the transaction -- it will be the provider configured earlier. Instead, check the before and after balance of provider.wallet.publicKey.
